# How to Sum All Digits In A Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]I know how to sum all digits in a cell using the following formula:=SUMPRODUCT(1*MID(A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2))),1)) But how do I do this for a range of cells oriented left to right not vertically? I want the output to be the row under the data not beside it. Please see attached screenshot.

I want to sum the numbers in cell B2, C2, D2, E2 and G2 so that is 7, 4, 5, 6, 9 and 9. And then I want to add those six numbers together. So that is two outputs for each main row for a spreadsheet that goes back to 2017. I have already done it manually in the attached screenshot but I am wondering if there is a macro I can use.

Thanks!

I tried doing this manually for each main row but it is time consuming. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Why don't you share the desired output e.g. for the cells in `H2:I5` (8 values)?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=MAP(A1:F1,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--MID(x,SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),1))))
```

If you have multiple rows that you need to squeeze these rows inbetween, then try:

[image]

Formula in `I1`:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(A:G,A:A<>""),REDUCE(TAKE(x,1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)-1),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(y,INDEX(x,b+1),VSTACK(a,y,HSTACK(TAKE(y,,1),MAP(DROP(y,,1),LAMBDA(c,SUM(--MID(c,SEQUENCE(LEN(c)),1))))))))))
```

If you also need the totals then it's a matter of nesting some `HSTACK()` functions in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this VBA code:

```
Sub AddSum()

Dim sumCellNumber As Long
sumCellNumber = 8

For rw = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count      ' Skip headers
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value <> "" Then    ' Date cell
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, sumCellNumber).Formula = "=SUM(B" & rw & ":G" & rw & ")" ' Set formula to sum the colums
        If sumCellNumber = 8 Then ' Change the position of the sum cell and background color
            ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, sumCellNumber).Interior.ColorIndex = 17 ' Result in H column
            sumCellNumber = 9
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, sumCellNumber).Interior.ColorIndex = 27 ' Result in I column
            sumCellNumber = 8
        End If
    End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

What it does is:

- Get all used rows from the active worksheet
- If the date column is not empty
- Then sets the `SUM` formula that adds the numbers from B to G column
- The result is shown in either H or I column using the background [index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex) according to the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the following might help:

To Sum the digits in a single cell:

```
=SUM(--MID(B2,SEQUENCE(LEN(B2)),1))
```

To Sum the digits in a range of cells:

```
=LET(digits,TEXTJOIN(,,B2:G2),SUM(--MID(digits, SEQUENCE(LEN(digits)),1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click in cell H2
2. Type in =Sum(B2:G2)
3. Press ENTER
4. Click on H2 again
5. Drag the little black box on the bottom right of the cell down to copy the formula for all the rows.

Comment: Can you clarify that? I don't understand.

Comment: Sure.
1. Click in cell H2
2. Type in =Sum(B2:G2)
3. Press ENTER
4. Click on H2 again
5. Drag the little black box on the bottom right of the cell down to copy the formula for all the rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you want to sum the digits of a number, but I remember from primary school this was a way to know if a number was divisble by 9: if the sum of the digits of a number are divisble by 9, then the number itself is too.
I quickly realised that this could be done recursively (e.g. the sum of the digits of 2345678 is 35, and the sum of those digits can be taken too, resulting in 8, so not divisble by 9).

If this is what you're aiming for, you can turn the whole thing around, and instead of taking the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits ..., you can check modulo 9, resulting in this formula:

```
=IF(MOD($B4,9)=0,9,MOD($B4,9))
```

(The `=IF()` construction avoids the sum to be equal to zero.)

Hereby a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]